# How to capture twitter users follow and unfollow events in python

Tags: python, twitter

I have been trying to capture the time which a user follow another user
in twitter but I get stuck. this is what I have for now.

```
import tweepy 
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream


#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = '...'
consumer_secret = '...'
access_token = '...'
access_secret = '...'

class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_event(self, event):

         if event.event == 'follow':
            time = event.created_at
            print(time)
            source_user = event.source
            target_user = target_user
            some_process(time, source_user, target_user)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)

    stream.sitestream(follow=['31415926','5358979'])
```

Comment: What issues are you having with that code?

Comment: it gives no output. it want to print the time which user1 follow user2 as in  follow=['31415926','5358979']

Comment: You could create a dict within an array, so that you can access follows[0]['time'], follows[0]['user1'] etc

Comment: Thank you LeuanG. but  I am not clear with what you are saying. could please give me more hint. e.g by adding your answer to my code.

Comment: I'll see what I can do in the morning. It's 1am here.

Comment: yeah, same time with me . okay, thanks.